# AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) -- How do I change StageName?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) to create a lambda with an API endpoint.

In my SAM template.yaml I have a getUser lambda with a /user endpoint.

**template.yaml**

```
Resources:
  GetUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: handler.getUser
      Timeout: 300
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Events:
        GetUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /user
            Method: get
```

When I deploy this using AWS CLI it successfully creates the lambda and endpoint, but with an API Gateway Stage confusingly named "Stage". I want to change stage name to something else, like "Prod". How do I change stage name?

Here's where stage name is defined in the cloudformation template after it is deployed. I want "StageName": "Stage" to be something like "StageName": "Prod".

```
"ServerlessRestApiDeployment": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
  "Properties": {
    "RestApiId": {
      "Ref": "ServerlessRestApi"
    },
    "StageName": "Stage"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to remove the `Stage` StageName, but when I deploy using SAM, I set a dynamic StageName in my GatewayAPI deployment using:

`Properties:
      StageName: !Ref "STAGE_VARIABLE"`

I have a different stack for each environment, so there is a `prod` API with a `prod` stage and a `dev` API with a `dev` stage.  I found this easier than have multiple stage deployments of the same GatewayAPI

Comment: Hey Brian, bit of an aside, but I'm trying to set up multiple stacks for deploying different stages at the moment, any chance you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you share your SAM file? where you put this StageName in?

Comment: I do this but an error stating that a stage with that name already exists in the stack

Answer (score 3):

To add another stage to an existing API, use a vanilla CFT stage resource. Docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html
A transform modifies the API to raw CFTs before deployment when using the SAM CLI, but it supports raw resources and you can reference the dynamic deployment resource using a .Deployment suffix. You should be able to just add the resource and reference your API values via the ref intrinsic. Check out the details here: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi

```
# assuming there is a AWS::Serverless::Api resource named Api
ProdApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      DeploymentId: !Ref Api.Deployment
```

There was a bug in the SAM CLI that autogenerated a "Stage" stage. To remove the default generated "stage" stage, upgrade your sam cli to the latest, and add a globals section setting the openapi version:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
```

See https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/191 for the details. This will prevent new spawns, but you will have to delete the stage manually if it was already deployed as SAM is stateless in nature.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for.  I think it's fairly average from aws to not have multi-stages for serverless.